# How does compiler behaves when swift and objective c is used in the same project?

Tags: objective-c-swift-bridge

Swift does more of the work in compile time like memory allocation for properties and Objective C does same work in run time.
Swift uses optimize compiler . If there is mix and match i.e. same project with swift code and objective c the which compiler will be used swift or objective c and how will it behave for compile time and run time in respect to swift and objective c.